# jqplot using remote json data

Tags: php, json, jqplot

i am using jqplot to track stock quotes, and i have static data at the moment that i am using and im taking a period of time from that data for the chart and sorting the high of day from that to display a trend.

my problem at the moment is i am having a really hard time figuring out how to take this data that is json_encode() and bringing it into my jqplot.

if you go here `http://www.evz.in/chronovestor/?scope=daily` you can see the data i am using, now i need to bring that data to jqplot, either using that url or something(this is were i am confused)

this is the jqplot setup i would like to use for this if possible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Our ajax data renderer which here retrieves a text file.
    // it could contact any source and pull data, however.
    // The options argument isn't used in this renderer.
    var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
        var ret = null;
        $.ajax({
            // have to use synchronous here, else the function
            // will return before the data is fetched
            async: false,
            url: url,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data) {
                ret = data;
            }
        });
        return ret;
    };

    // The url for our json data
    var jsonurl = "./jsondata.txt";

    // passing in the url string as the jqPlot data argument is a handy
    // shortcut for our renderer.  You could also have used the
    // "dataRendererOptions" option to pass in the url.
    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
        title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer",
        dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
        dataRendererOptions: {
            unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your link appears to be a html format with JSON data encoded inside it. Jqplot couldn't read html with JSON combined in it. Try to parse out the JSON in order to use Jqplot with remote file.

Comment: Anyway, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699445/populate-jqplot-from-remote-json) worked for me.  However, it uses different JSON format. You can check the Jsfiddle for it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tSHRv/).